# Node js vs React some doubts regarding errors

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, development-environment

Now my doubt is that if I want to delete a comment only if it was posted by me (works for all the logged in user in same manner) should I check this condition in backend or frontend ? Which one would be good enough ? Any performance issues or any best practices ?

Not only deleting comments but even updating it ?

Answer (score 1):

Both frontend and backend should do the checking.

**Front-end:** Mostly for UX, e.g. hiding the `Delete Post` button if the user is not the creater.

**Back-end:** The actual place where the validation should be conducted.

Why? If you do validation on the front-end only, then it is extremely easy to bypass the UI (remember, JS is executed **on the client-side**) to perform some operations that users are not supposed to. e.g. Making an HTTP request directly to the server without using the UI.

On the other hand, if you don't do validation on the front-end, the UI may be very confusing because users are able to interact with some of the UI element which he is not supposed to (e.g. pressing the `Delete Post` button, while getting a pop up say "permission denied").

Comment: Ya thanks a lot, I did validation in Backend as well by using req.user and not the entire req.body. one last thing I would like to get in contact with you for more doubts if that's possible ?